# How can I pass a parameter using Javascript / Jquery to a page in a modal dialog

Tags: javascript, jquery, modal-dialog

I need an advice to know the best way to open a link in a modal dialog.

I would like to pass a parameter from a link to a modal window so I can use it to perform a database query in a PHP file and show some data as a form to perform an insert.

I HAVE looked through this site and others and can't find a straight forward way to do this.

I have tried to use Boostrap Modal but it does not manage to open a link from another page or at least I don’t know how to do it. I have also tried Jquery Modal https://jquerymodal.com/  but this modal cannot be opened from Javascript.

I need to use Javascript because I want to be able to pass the current value of a field to a page in a modal dialog using onclick. 
The Jquery code should be something like this:

```
function getvalue(varid) {
var vproid = $("#plato_"+varid).val();
var vuser = <?php echo $user; ?>
window.location.href =  "detail.php?user="+vuser+"&product="+vproid; 
//Maybe open modal from here
};
```

HTML CODE

```
<a href="# "   id="1" onclick=”getvalue(this.id)”> Insert Details </a> 
 <input type="hidden" name="opcion" id="plato_1" value="25"/>
```

Comment: Changing `window.location.href` will typically cause a page transfer.  Which will navigate away from the page.  So attempting to open a modal on a page being transfered away from seems like, not what you want?

Comment: Exactly. I want to stay on the same page. I do not want to refresh my page because I will lose other values being inserted. That's why I need to use a modal dialog.